# Send Signal From Child To Parent On Mouse Click Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a MainWindow, a DockWidget and a QGLWidget inside it. I am drawing circles inside the QGLWidget. I want to print the x and y coordinates of the place that I am clicking to the labels inside DockWidget.

I would be glad if someone could show me the way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the `QWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *)` or `QWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *)` of the QGLWidget and create a signal for sending the x and y. It means you have to create own class inherithing from QGLWidget.
It could look like this:

```
void MyGLWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
  emit printXY(event->pos());
}
```

and in the MyGLWidget.h:

```
signals:
void printXY(const QPointF& clickedPos);
```

then create a slot in the DockWidget:

```
public slots:
void onPrintXY(const QPointF& clickedPos);
```

and connect it in the place where you create the MyGLWidget. I suppose in some function of the DockWidget like:

```
void DockWidget::createGLWidget()
{
  MyGLWidget widget = new MyGLWidget;
  connect(widget, &MyGLWidget::printXY, this, &DockWidget::onPrintXY);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm! Do you know where exactly I can find more information about emitting?

Comment: @BUY you're welcome. You can find more info in the documentation here [link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)